# windows 11 : command to prevent a USB port to turn off (to save energy)?

Tags: usb, windows-11, energy-saving

After Window 11 updates, some USB ports come back to default settings that is "allow to turn off power to save energy". Usually, for each port, I disable this power function. I use Labview, and my experiment runs for several days. Then it stops randomly due to USB port that turned off. So I would like to use a command prompt to control this setting, rather than doing that manually. If I know the command, then I will implement this command in Labview program.

Comment: If you set power management in Device Manager, I think it  just has to be set once.

Comment: thank you John, yes, that is also what I though, but I found that after any update (and there are quite a lot ...), some settings came back to default, including USB power saving. And this is a problem for us, doing research with long time scale measurements with many instruments in usb hubs.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Command Prompt by pressing Win + R on your keyboard, typing "cmd," and pressing Enter.

In the Command Prompt window, type the following command and press Enter:

```
powercfg /devicequery wake_armed
```

This command will display a list of devices that are currently allowed to wake up the system from sleep.

Identify the USB device that you want to prevent from entering sleep mode in the list.

To prevent a USB device from waking up the system, type the following command in the Command Prompt, replacing "Device Name" with the name of the USB device you want to target:

```
powercfg /devicedisablewake "Device Name"
```

For example, if the USB device name is "USB Root Hub," the command will be:

```
powercfg /devicedisablewake "USB Root Hub"
```

This command will disable the USB device's ability to wake up the system from sleep.

Repeat the above command for each USB device you want to prevent from entering sleep mode.

Comment: Thank you Nuno, I will try to set those commands in Labview, thank you so much for  the explanations, that are very clear.